# Twilio and Transcription in Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am attempting to transcribe recorded audio from a Dial-Verb in Twilio.  I've installed both the VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription add-on and the IBM Watson Speech to Text add-on.  The documentation for both add-ons appears to be sparse. Ideally, there would be a tutorial and sample code but I have been unsuccessful in locating.

Specifically, I am using Node.js and am parsing a dual-channel recording from a Dial-Verb.

```
<Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual" action="https://my-twilio-url.twil.io/myendpoint" >
    <Number>+8005551212</Number> 
</Dial>
```

I am able to pick up the location of the recorded conversation in the Node.js that powers the endpoint, but after that I'm a little lost.

Do any tutorials exist in Node.js for either of the two transcription services?

Comment: I don't think there's a tutorial I'm afraid. Have you set up the callback URL for the Add on in the Twilio console? When you receive the callback you should make a request to the `payloads` URL in the JSON you receive and that will get you the transcription.